# Word for a person who sews at an industrial level

Tags: word-choice

Some other questions.

Is it ok to say that someone is a "sewer"? Is that the noun for that verb?

So, I'm basically looking for the word "sewer" but at an industrial level. Mainly because in my native language (Spanish) we do have a word, and I would like to use it in a project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* the noun for the verb, but it is not often used because of the other meaning of *sewer* (a pipe for used water and human waste), although the pronunciations are different.

For a factory worker, I would suggest *sewing machine operator*.

Comment: That's a good suggestion; another common term is "garment worker."

Answer (score 1):

industrial seamstress or sewer

> What does an Industrial Seamstress do?  [...] Be aware, though, as an
>   **Industrial Seamstress**, you don’t spend your days attaching buttons to blouses and designing wedding dresses. No, the job of an Industrial
>   Seamstress is the Rambo of seamstressing. Also known as an
>   **Industrial Sewer**, an Industrial Seamstress wrangles 50-pound rolls of heavyweight material from one project to the next.The equipment
>   looks like it belongs on a construction site rather than a sewing
>   facility, and the products created are anything but dainty.

[seamstress and sewer](https://www.careermatch.com/job-prep/career-insights/profiles/industrial-seamstress/)

The capital letters in the article are for emphasis.

Comment: This had me wondering what a male [seamstress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seamstress) would be called. Apparently, [seamster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seamster) is a gender-neutral term.